# How to adjust how high/tall an isotope-item is set to

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble figuring out why and how to adjust the height of an isotope-item.

- I have a page with products on it and some of the buttons at the bottom of the column are being slightly covered by the image in the next row. I'm thinking if I can set the height on the isotope-item, it might fix the issue.

Currently, it looks like the width and height are being declared dynamically. I'm not quite sure if this is a Javascript issue or if I can fix with CSS.

Sorry, I don't have much code to show, but this is the inline style shown in the browser:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 isotope-item" data-filter="Digital" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 493px;">
```

I also tried to just add the following with no luck:

```
.isotope-item {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

And here's a link to the page:

https://www.ucswireless.oiw11.com/solutions/p25-two-way-radios.htm

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap classes (col-xs, col-sm) add width to your div element. As for the height, min-height only sets the minimum height, so if the content exceeds the min-height, it will stretch even further. To set the height and width, use:

```
.isotope-item {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

But make sure the css does not conflict with bootstrap classes (col-xs-12 will set its own width).

**EDIT:**

I had a look at the webpage you linked to. The issue is not exactly in the height of the isotope-item. You give the box a height of 500, but the content (text specifically) is too big to fit - so it 'falls out' of the 500px height. Why doesn't the bottom box get pushed down? Because the box has position: absolute, so it doesn't align on the grid as it should, it has specific coordinates it's set to be on.

The easiest way to fix it? Add height: 500px and overflow: auto to your boxes. But it's not going to look pretty. Next best thing - limit the amount of text that can go inside the box.

Other than that, you need to redo the grid and not use position absolute, so the boxes align themselves based on their heights.

Comment: I tried to add the height and width to the .isotope-item, the width seems to work, but not the height. Any thoughts?

Comment: See my edit, I didnt have enough space in the comment section

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll have to re-evaluate these boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The width is given by bootstrap `col` classes (in your case `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4`). I would not advice you to override those classes, instead adapt your grid in order to obtain the result you desire.

[More on bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)